# Can not target the last child of an element

Tags: php, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I want to disable border-bottom of the last elemnt inside a while loop, but it doesn't work...
This is the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">  
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>                                   
          <h2 class="special-project-title"><?php the_title()?></h2> <br/>
         <div class="post-meta special-project-meta"><?php mida_post_meta()?></div><br/>
         <a class="more-link spaciel-project-more" href="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo __('Read More', 'mida')?></a><br/>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>    
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
</div>
```

"spaciel-project-more" has a border bottom, but I want the last one to not have a border bottom.. can't figure this out..

CSS:

```
.spaciel-project-more{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.spaciel-project-more:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: last-child targets the last element in a group - not the last of kind - that is why it is not working - since you have the loop code in place why not just add a class to the link when displaying the last post item?

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, so far I got this which looks fine - https://jsfiddle.net/mb4sfw74/

Comment: My mistake, I used last-of-type and it worked.. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the `:last-child` because there is some other content after that. You can use `:last-of-type`:

```
.spaciel-project-more:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dymvdp8k/)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your style in css may help you

```
.spaciel-project-more:last-child{
    border-bottom:0px;
}
```